# replacing a string with other but not the substring

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, substring

```
BCXADServer() : Server(), m_bBet(false) {}
```

I want to replace Server() with  where it is alone and not at any other place like here it is in BCXADServer()

so the desired out put is -

```
BCXADServer() : <some-string>, m_bBet(false) {}
```

but I am getting

```
BCXAD<some-string> : <some-string>, m_bBet(false) {}
```

it is replacing at both the places.

like this it is at multiple places in file.

I did try with re.sub and replace() method but it is always replacing everywhere instead of desired place.

Please help me to resolve that issue.

Comment: You can just do: `>>> your_string.replace(' Server()','<other-string>')`

Answer (score 1):

use `regex` with `\b` to match with work boundary so it won't match the word if its within the substring of other word

```
import re
s = 'BCXADServer() : Server(), m_bBet(false) {}'
re.sub(r'\bServer\(\)', 'XXX', s)  # replace Server() with XXX
# 'BCXADServer() : XXX, m_bBet(false) {}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your input with your desired string using different manners.

For example:

**With regex:**

```
import re
my_input_string = "BCXADServer() : Server(), m_bBet(false) {}"
pattern = r'\bServer\(\)'
to_replace = "<some-string>"
replaced_string = re.sub(pattern, to_replace, my_input_string)
print(replaced_string)
```

Output:

```
BCXADServer() : <some-string>, m_bBet(false) {}
```

**Dividing your string and using `replace()`:**

```
my_input_string = "BCXADServer() : Server(), m_bBet(false) {}"

def replace_string(input_string = "", replace_string = ""):
    b = list(input_string.split(":"))
    return ":".join([b[0], b[1].replace("Server()", replace_string)])

replaced_string = replace_string(my_input_string, "<some-string>")
print(replaced_string)
```

Output:

```
BCXADServer() : <some-string>, m_bBet(false) {}
```